# Setting up CORS with Faust webview

Tags: cors, aiohttp, faust

I'm attempting to directly post information to a Kaka topic via a Faust web view as per their example. However, I'm getting the familiar CORS issue in the response.
Looking into the docs only leads me to see that I need to use aiohttp-cors to set up the options, but it's really unclear how to do this with a Faust application.

Below is a cut down version of my server-side code:

```py
import faust
from faust.web import Request, Response, View
import asyncio
from models.models_2 import AlarmFilterRequest

BROKER_LIST=['kafka://localhost:9092', 'kafka://localhost:9093', 'kafka://localhost:9094']

app = faust.App('alarm-filter-stream', broker=BROKER_LIST, store='memory://')

alarm_filter_requests_topic = app.topic('alarm-filter-requests', value_type=AlarmFilterRequest, value_serializer='json')

@app.agent(alarm_filter_requests_topic)
async def new_filter_request(stream):
  async for event in stream.events():
    # do some processing
    ...

@app.page('/filter')
class test_page_view(View):  
  async def post(self, request: Request) -> Response:
    # Here we want to produce to the alarm_filter_requests topic
    return self.json({"timestamp":f"{datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')}"})
```

I simply can't figure out how to set the allowed origins and headers etc. to avoid the CORS errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Vikram Patki on the slack channel for offering an answer.

It's not easy to find in the [Faust documentation](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/settings.html#web-cors-options) so hopefully anyone else with the same issue will find this solution quickly.

The trick is to include the cors details when you define the app like so:

```py
app = faust.App(
  'app-name',
  broker=BROKER_LIST,
  store=STORE,
  web_cors_options={
    "*": ResourceOptions(
      allow_credentials=False,
      allow_methods="*",
      expose_headers="*",
      allow_headers="*",
    )
  }
)
```

Then to use anything other than get requests, you need to set up as per the [example in the docs](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#http-verbs-get-post-put-delete).